# Script to make colorful QR codes

Tags: qr-code

There are plenty of scripts out there that can generate a black and white QR code. 
I have a script on my website that will generate the QR code. 
However, I wanted a script that allows the user to modify the black and white QR code and customize it to a more colorful QR code.

Are there open source scripts that will allow the user to customize their QR code with color?

So that they can select

QR color
Background color
Use color gradient
Gradient style: Radial
2nd QR color for gradient
Rounded Corners

Upload logo

These sites do not offer their scripts for open source

- http://www.qrhacker.com/
- http://uqr.me/2012/06/qr-code-beautifier/

Comment: this sort of system is likely to produce barcodes that cannot be read. most scanners are B&W only, and need a certain amount of contrast between the barcode "on" and "off" elements to be able to read them.

Comment: @MarcB That is sometimes true, but it's far from necessary. Look at the barcode on a Coca-Cola can... silver-on-white.

Comment: On scanners that are B&W only, the image is seen as though it has been grey scaled. So long as there is sufficient contrast between the two colors when grey scaled, then use of the colors in question should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a round-about way to do colour gradients - I had a need recently to do this and it took some figuring out because, as you observed, those that can are closed source and the open source alternatives don't do it.

1. Generate the gradient as an image.  Someone wrote [a helpful PHP class](http://planetozh.com/blog/my-projects/images-php-gd-gradient-fill/comment-page-2/) to generate the image for you in a variety of directions and styles - one of which is radial (well, ellipse anyway).
2. Use a library like endroid's [qr-code](https://github.com/endroid/qr-code) library.
3. Reload the QR code in GD and set the QR code colour as transparent.
4. Overlay the QR code onto your gradient image.